# Lifetime Borrow Rules

Tags: rust

Is there a good explanation of Rust's borrow rules: not just why the borrow rules imply safety, but why safety implies that these must be the rules?

The Rust book explains that borrows must follow these rules:

1. There can be 1 mutable borrow
   OR
2. There can be any number of immutable borrows
3. These are the only allowed borrows

The book explains that this is necessary because if there were two mutable borrows, they might both modify the same memory at the same time.

I found this unsatisfying. If there is the original variable and the mutable borrow, isn't that already 2 place where the memory can be modified at the same time? I know both cannot be used at the same time, but why is 2 references special? We could imagine that 3 mutable references are allowed, but you can only mutate with the 1st when the other 2 are gone, and you can only mutate with the 2nd when the 3rd is gone. Why is it 2?

If I could promise the compiler that my code will only run on one thread, like the dreaded Python GIL, would any of these rules be necessary?

Answer (score 2):

> If there is the original variable and the mutable borrow, isn't that already 2 place where the memory can be modified at the same time?

No, because the compiler will not allow you to use them both at the same time.

> If I could promise the compiler that my code will only run on one thread, like the dreaded Python GIL, would any of these rules be necessary?

Yes:

```rust
let mut v = vec![1];
let r = &v[0];
v.push(2);
println!("{}", r);
```

`push` may allocate, invalidating `r`.

Comment: In your example, isn't that a problem because there is a reference at all (not a mutable one)? Is there a single-thread example where mutability is specifically a problem?

Comment: My question is the same as before: why is 2 special? We could imagine that 3 mutable references are allowed, but you can only mutate with the 1st when the other 2 are gone, and you can only mutate with the 2nd when the 3rd is gone. We can extend to N. –

Comment: Yes, but mutability appears in `v` being borrowed as `&mut` to call `push`. If it was another method that only needs `&`, there would be no problem. I changed `r` in example from `&mut` to `&` for clarity.

Comment: 2 is not special: Rust allows N mutable borrows as long as only one is known to be "live" at each point.

Comment: @Acorn, is there an example like this that does not use sliced references (i.e, taking a reference of a small portion from a bigger object)?

Answer (score 0):

The original variable cannot be used as long as the mutable borrow is alive, so using the variable will invalidate it, causing later uses of it to err.

You can observe it yourself:

```rust
let mut v = 0;
let r = &mut v;
v;
r;
```

```
error[E0503]: cannot use `v` because it was mutably borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:5:1
  |
4 | let r = &mut v;
  |         ------ borrow of `v` occurs here
5 | v;
  | ^ use of borrowed `v`
6 | r;
  | - borrow later used here
```

[Playgroung](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ae37f4452f14f606501ccb09d60c5602).

It is tricky to observe because most of the thinks you think "use" the variable in fact creates a reference to it: for example, `println!("{v}")` expands into:

```rust
::std::io::_print(::core::fmt::Arguments::new_v1(
    &["", "\n"],
    &[::core::fmt::ArgumentV1::new_display(&v)],
));
```

And thus the error message is also different:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:5:15
  |
4 |     let r = &mut v;
  |             ------ mutable borrow occurs here
5 |     println!("{v}");
  |               ^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
6 |     r;
  |     - mutable borrow later used here
  |
  = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45a4c05d3cf94b191549b72ce2ee8c89).

As far as I'm aware, the only things that do not create a reference is assigning to the variable and moving/copying it, or just naming it, which is pretty useless.

Answer (score -1):

If a mutable borrow is made before an immutable borrow, and then used, the code won't compile.

For example, this works:

```
#[allow(unused)]
pub fn main() {
    let mut x = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let y = &x;
    let z = &mut x;
    z[1] = 3;
    z.push(6);
}
```

However, this does not:

```
#[allow(unused)]
pub fn main() {
    let mut x = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let y = &x;
    let z = &mut x;
    z[1] = 3;
    z.push(6);
    println!("{}", y[1]);
}
```

... giving the error output:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `x` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> main.rs:5:13
  |
4 |     let y = &x;
  |             -- immutable borrow occurs here
5 |     let z = &mut x;
  |             ^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
8 |     println!("{}", y[1]);
  |                    - immutable borrow later used here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Which, essentially, works as you'd expect. You can have as many immutable borrows as you want, until a mutable borrow, and then you can have only one mutable borrow, to the exclusion of any other previous borrows.

Also, you can't modify the original variable either while the mutable borrow is used.

```
#[allow(unused)]
pub fn main() {
    let mut x = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let z = &mut x;
    z[1] = 3;
    x[2] = 4;
    z[3] = 5;
}
```

... giving the error output:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `x` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> main.rs:6:5
  |
4 |     let z = &mut x;
  |             ------ first mutable borrow occurs here
5 |     z[1] = 3;
6 |     x[2] = 4;
  |     ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
7 |     z[3] = 5;
  |     - first borrow later used here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

In short, borrowing rules enforce that only variable is allowed to mutate the data at a time. If the mutable borrow is no longer used, then we can freely mutate the original variable, or use immutable borrows of it.

For example, `z` is never used again so this code is fine:

```
#[allow(unused)]
pub fn main() {
    let mut x = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let z = &mut x;
    z[1] = 3;
    x[2] = 4;
}
```

Comment: This is what the rules *are*, and well stated, but my question was *why* these are the rules. Also, when you do a mutable borrow, naively, it seems there are 2 mutable references: the original variable and the borrowed variable. Why isn't this a problem?

Comment: @Test Because you can't use one of the 2 mutable references. So you can't modify the data in 2 locations at once, which I show in one of the examples. You cannot use `x` and `z` when both are mutable references. You can use `x` before `z` exists, or after `z` is no longer used, but you cannot use `z` then `x` then `z`. In short, only one mutable variable can be used at a time.

Comment: As for the reason why you can only one mutable borrow at a time, you explain the reason right here: `The book explains that this is necessary because if there were two mutable borrows, they might both modify the same memory at the same time.` But, since you can't use both the mutable variable and the mutable reference at the same time, you don't have the condition you mention above.

Comment: In short, your explanation already explains why the rule exists, which was your question, but your second question @Test is why your specific example doesn't cause issues like 2 mutable borrows, and that's simply because the compiler doesn't let you use both the mutable variable and the mutable reference together.

Comment: I guess the question is: why is 2 special? We could imagine that 3 mutable references are allowed, but you can only mutate with the 1st when the other 2 are gone, and you can only mutate with the 2nd when the 3rd is gone. We can extend to N.

Comment: It is not really two. While something is borrowed, you can't do anything with it. Borrowing is like a temporary transfer of ownership.

Comment: I mean you can, as long as you don't use the reference. But that's pointless: the reason it works is the compiler knows it isn't used so only one mutable reference is used at a time.